# Are there any short-term survivable locations in the solar system, outside of Earth?

Tags: atmosphere, oxygen, survivability

Are there any known natural locations (i.e. not counting ISS) in our solar system (outside of Earth) where a human being in street clothes (i.e. without a spacesuit or other specialized equipment) could survive for a few minutes?

If not, which known locations come the closest to that?

Comment: [Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon)) has a similar atmospheric pressure to Earth's, but its atmosphere is unbreathable & the temperature is too cold, at -179.5 C. Floating at a particular elevation in the atmosphere if Venus, might be possible, but all other celestial bodies, in our solar system, are too hostile for us to be able to walk on them without some form of survival equipment.

Comment: No other body in the solar system has an oxygen atmosphere.

Comment: This limits survival time to few minutes. Still interesting.

Comment: The world record for static apnea (holding your breath underwater, without any movement) is just shy of 12 minutes for males and over 9 minutes for females. The Guinness Book World Record for holding your breath is almost 25 minutes (with pre-breathing of pure oxygen which is not allowed by official AIDA rules, hence the large difference in the two records) for males and over 18 minutes for females. So, oxygen in the atmosphere is not necessarily a requirement for the "several minutes" of survival.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with survive ? Survive while being conscious, or cooled down as in the answer below ? And should the natural location be accessible  with nowadays means ?

Comment: @Cornelis survive meaning that you can be teleported (via hand-waving magic) to that location, spend a few minutes there, then be teleported back home again and still be alive the next day :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner If you reason this way, the subsurface of Mars for instance, could also be a survivable location. You don't need to be drowned I think to survive in a cold environment.

Comment: @OP, if that is your criteria, you could be teleported to the hard vacuum of space for maybe a little over a minute, and if you were teleported back to Earth's surface right away, after a few minutes of recovery you probably would not even need medical attention.  The one caveat is if you were holding your breath, your lungs might rupture, although I question if it would even be possible to hold your breath, as air would rush out your nose due to the pressure difference.  
Psychological recovery might take quite a bit longer...

Comment: in a pinch there's always [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRuhS.jpg)

Comment: @RC_23 It would not be possible to hold your breath and you would certainly die of lung damage in that scenario.  While a lack of oxygen will not kill in that time frame the air exiting your lungs too fast will.  So long as the hole in your compartment is less than IIRC about 1% of it's surface area you survive if rescued fast enough, beyond that the airflow shreds your lungs.  Bowman's stunt in 2001 doesn't work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As already commented by Fred, Venus is your best bet. Not at surface level – both temperature and pressure are way too high there – but at ca. 50 km elevation, where both are actually quite similar to Earth at sea-level.

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1ELk.png)

<sup>(From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Atmosphere_of_Venus&oldid=1107757177))</sup>

Of course, the sulfuric acid would start eating on you, but the concentration isn't that high, so you would certainly survive for a while. Keep your eyes shut and don't breathe in – you would only get CO₂ anyway, which would of course quickly suffocate you. But people *can* survive some minutes of holding their breath, so that's ok.

None of the other inner planets or their moons have nearly enough of an atmosphere. The body can tolerate vacuum much worse than oxygen-less atmosphere. Further out, namely Jupiter, Saturn and Titan, you do find atmospheres where you could have enough pressure, but only at very cold temperature. I suppose you might survive some minutes on Titan in Antarctic-grade clothing, but hardly in street clothing.

Comment: Without an aircraft (Is a balloon or other aircraft specialized equipment?), you'd reach the ground in just over a hundred seconds.

Comment: @Joooeey Venus's atmosphere is so thick, that a Venus Flagship Probe Proposal [(PDF, see graphic on page 23)](https://science.nasa.gov/science-red/s3fs-public/atoms/files/Venus%20Flagship%20Mission.pdf) estimates that **free-falling** (after backshell separation) from 59 km with a downward velocity of 28 m/s, it will take **55 minutes** to reach the surface.

Comment: @NickT would that be long enough to corrode the guy in street clothes before he hits the ground?

Comment: @bobflux the fall is much faster at the survivable altiture (basically same as a fall on Earth). Only as you get into the denser parts of the atmosphere do you slow down, but then it's probably the pressure-cooking that you should worry about first, not the acid.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Damn! That's true.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Humans can survive immersion in water as deep as 600 meters (tested). That's 60 bar. So you'd stay alive - except for the effect of the sulphuric acid on your body.

Comment: @ZOMVID-21 60 bar in temperate water while breathing a carefully pressure-adjusted heliox mixture, that's one thing. Rapidly falling into 60 bar of 200°C hot CO₂ is an entirely different story.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Temperature is a valid danger. Pressure is not.

Answer (score 16):

No place other than Earth has available oxygen. This limits survivability.

Nevertheless, if a body is cooled down significantly, the immediate deadly effects of anoxia can be pushed away as much as over an hour.

Universitetsykehuset i Nord-Norge (University Hospital of North Norway) has seen a few dozen cases of drowning in cold environments over the years. About 30% survive, with the lowest surviving body temperature being 13.7 ºC.

Yes, Hypotermia is a likely death. But better a probable death than a certain one.

Consider then the hypothesized oceans below the ice of Europa or Enceladus as "short-term survivable locations". Given specialized care not too long after being submerged in them, you have *some* chance of surviving.

Comment: Relevant: [Jan Harald Nilsen - Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation and
Rewarming from Accidental Hypothermia](https://munin.uit.no/bitstream/handle/10037/24126/thesis.pdf?sequence=10&isAllowed=y)

Comment: Hence one of the cardinal rules of emergency medicine: they ain't dead until they're warm and dead.

Comment: If you reason this way, the subsurface of Mars would also be a location where a body could survive. Where would you need an ocean for then ?

Comment: @Cornelis Would the subsurface of Mars be warm enough? [apparently yes](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14875/what-is-the-temperature-55-km-beneath-the-surface-of-mars), so that's another place. Might be even more inaccessible though.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys You're ignoring the pressure. At around 1/150th the sea level pressure of Earth you have some real problems. Your breath is torn from your lungs, which are then torn appart by the rapid expansion of gasses in the blood. They water in your body suddenly has a boiling point of -5°C, so every exposed cell ruptures from low temperature steam build-up. Your mucous membranes dessicate in seconds, then explode in showers of dust. Do you want me to go on? Long story short, you die in seconds.

Comment: @Corey thermodynamically, yes, but kinetically, not really. Such things take *some* amount of time, things won't just 'explode'. For an extreme comparison, diamonds aren't 'exploding' into graphite.

Comment: @NickT Might have used a bit much dramatic licence there, but the point still stands. The cell walls rupture from the internal pressure in rather short order as the water in the cell turns to a gas. The human might not explode, but the cells certainly do 

Comment: @Corey Survivability of vacuum is the subject of some debate. I think the majority of opinions is less dramatic than yours. "[People can likely survive exposure to vacuum conditions for at least a couple of minutes](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/survival-in-space-unprotected-possible/)" which makes most locations in the solar system similar in terms of survivability.

Comment: The center of the sun is 'short term' survivable, for some definition of 'short'...

Comment: I've heard of surgery where they took the core body temperature even lower than that.  Incredibly dangerous, but if you have to operate on the blood vessels of the brain there's no other way to do it.  The colder you go the more time before brain damage, but the greater the risk they can't bring you back.